# Check if display is off using CMD

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, powercfg

Currently my Windows 10 PC turns off its display after 10 min (A setting under "Power Options").

I have a DIY batch script that loops every 2s in Windows background. However, this script doesn't work when the display is off. Is there any way to check if the monitor is turned off with powercfg or other means from cmd?

What I want is something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%n in (1,0,10) do (
  if !monitor!=off (
    echo do nothing
  ) else (
    echo do stuff
  )
  TIMEOUT 2
)
```

Comment: Batch can't do this. You will need software that can remember a display, because with hdmi and display port, if the monitor is turned off, the display is uninstalled until its powered on again, which means you can't query if the monitor is off as the monitor is gone from the system at that point.

Comment: How about getting the idle time from cmd? Or check if the screen is locked?

Comment: `quser` or `query user` (same command) will allow you to tell if a user is idle. You will still have to parse the command and search for the word IDLE vs ACTIVE and if no user is logged on at all, the user won't display, but that's probably something that won't happen in your usecase. But I realize if you don't move the mouse for a while, the user becomes idle, but that is not the same as screen locked etc. Quser will give the idle time though. Maybe using Powershell is better here. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39212183/easier-way-to-parse-query-user-in-powershell

Comment: for some reasons `quser` always returns idle time `None` no matter how long I've left my PC alone.

Comment: quser may show the user as disconnected if you lock the session. Keep in mind that any mouse movement to run the script will cause quser to detect activity. May need to use a script to query it periodically and write it to disk.

Comment: i did use a script that calls quser periodically and it always returns "None" under Idle